# Porque esta operacion no devuelve lo mismo?

Tags: javascript

El desplazamiento hacia la derecha con signo con un numero positivo devuelve `0` con el siguiente ejemplo:

```js
console.log(10 >> 5);
```

Si siguieramos de manera infinita haciendo lo mismo siempre nos dara `0`:

```js
console.log(10 >> 8);
```

Pero si el numero es negativo al llegar al limite maximo divisible nos devuelve `-1` en vez de cero:

```js
console.log(-10 >> 5);
```

Y si lo hacemos de manera infinita siempre nos devolvera `-1`.

Mi pregunta es... porque en el ultimo caso el valor devuelto siempre es `-1` cuando se llega al limite de division??, no deberia ser `0` al igual que en el caso donde el numero es positivo?

Si se intenta con ambos numeros negativos pasa lo mismo:

```js
console.log(-10 >> -8);
```

Se que no tiene sentido que se pueda desplazar a la derecha de manera negativa, pero en este caso tambien sigue devolviendo `-1` y no `0` o por defecto `-10` que era el numero original, porque pasa esto?

Es decir, comprenderia que devolviera `-10` en caso de que no hiciese ningun desplazamiento, pero en este caso al devolver un numero diferente al original presiento que aun asi se esta haciendo un desplazamiento.

Comment: Javascript usa codificación de complemento a 2 para los números negativos, por tanto -10 en binario quedaría ....111110110 repleto de unos a la izquierda hasta llegar a 32 bits. Al correrlo 5 lugares o más a la derecha obtendrás puros unos ....1111111 porque es un número negativo, y esos puros unos representan el número -1 en complemento de 2.

Comment: La mejor explicación con incluso los números en binarios, la encontrarás en la [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Right_shift). Checa [esto también](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_NOT).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para entender lo que está pasando conviene mirar los números que estás desplazando en binario. Para ello ejecutemos el siguiente script:

```js
const toBinary = n => (n >>> 0).toString(2);

let a = 10;
console.log("El valor de 10 en binario es: " + toBinary(a))

a = -10
console.log("El valor de -10 en binario es: " + toBinary(a))

a = -1
console.log("El valor de -1 en binario es: " + toBinary(a))
```

De mirar la representación en binario de los números negativos en `js` ya es posible arrojar luz al asunto, y es que [`javascript`](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_bitwise.asp#:%7E:text=JavaScript%20binary%20numbers,number%20plus%201%3A) usa [el complemento a 2](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complemento_a_dos) para representar los números negativos. Hallar el complemento a 2 para representar en binario un número negativo es sencillo y puede lograrse:

1. Obteniendo la representación binaria del valor absoluto del número. Por ejemplo, para `-10` el valor absoluto sería `10` y su representación binaria `1010`.
2. Remplazar 0s con 1s y 1s con 0s. (Recuerda que es un número de 32 bits, por tanto `11111111111111111111111111110101`).
3. Sumar 1 al número binario anterior. (`11111111111111111111111111110101` + `1` = `11111111111111111111111111110110`)

Esta representación hace que las operaciones de desplazamiento se comporten de una manera diferente a lo que podamos suponer.

> ¿por qué en el último caso el valor devuelto siempre es -1 cuando se llega al limite de division?

Al realizar la operación de desplazamiento hacia la derecha, `javascript` inserta un 0 o un 1 a la izquierda dependiendo si el número a desplazar es positivo o negativo.

Si el número a desplazar es positivo, se insertarán tantos ceros a la izquierda como se especifique en la operación, eliminándose la misma cantidad de cifras insertadas en la derecha del número. El caso límite se alcanza cuando se han insertado tantos ceros, que se han anulado todas las cifras significativas, quedando los 32 bits en cero, por tanto, el caso límite es cero.

En el caso de los números negativos, ante un desplazamiento hacia a la derecha se insertan unos a la izquierda,y de manera similar, se eliminan las misma cantidad de cifras que se insertaron de las cifras menos significativas. El caso límite se alcanza cuando se han insertado tantos unos como cifras significativas tenga el número, quedando puros unos, y por tanto, el valor -1.

```js
const toBinary = n => (n >>> 0).toString(2);

let a = 10;
for(let i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
   console.log(`El valor de ${a} >> ${i} en binario es: ${toBinary(a >> i)} y en decimal ${(a >> i)}`)
}

console.log("------------------------------------------")

a = -10;
for(let i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
    console.log(`El valor de ${a} >> ${i} en binario es: ${toBinary(a >> i)} y en decimal ${(a >> i)}`)
}
```

En el caso de números desplazados una cantidad negativa, ocurrirá siempre el caso límite. En este caso 0 si el número que va a ser desplazado es positivo, o -1, si el número es negativo.

```js
const toBinary = n => (n >>> 0).toString(2);

let a = 10;
for(let i = 0; i > -5; i--) {
   console.log(`El valor de ${a} >> ${i} en binario es: ${toBinary(a >> i)} y en decimal ${(a >> i)}`)
}

console.log("------------------------------------------")

a = -10;
for(let i = 0; i > -5; i--) {
    console.log(`El valor de ${a} >> ${i} en binario es: ${toBinary(a >> i)} y en decimal ${(a >> i)}`)
}
```